# SQL Binary Conversion vs .Net Binary Conversion

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, type-conversion, binary-data

I have a table in a MS SQL server like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Setting
(
   ID int NOT NULL,
   Value varbinary(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

The information in the Value column can be formatted as a string, boolean, integer, decimal, etc.  As an example:

```
INSERT INTO Setting (Value) VALUES (CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 5.4))
```

To select the data I could convert the values before returning the data to .Net, but I would prefer my select procedure to return the binary data and then perform the correct type conversion in .Net.  This way, I would be able to select multiple settings stored in different formats at the same time.

What I cannot figure out is how to convert the binary data returned into the correct types (particularly for integer and decimal).  The database returns the binary data in a byte array (byte[]), but conversion from a byte array to an integer or decimal seems to be poorly supported.

My fist inclination was to use System.Convert, but it does not support byte arrays.

My second solution was to use System.IO.BinaryWriter and System.IO.BinaryReader.  This method gave me this error: "Unable to read beyond the end of the stream."

Example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 2.3)";
byte[] bytes = (byte[])ExecuteSelect(cmd).Rows[0][0];
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.BinaryWriter br = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(ms);
br.Write(bytes);
System.IO.BinaryReader br2 = new System.IO.BinaryReader(ms);
decimal d = br2.ReadDecimal();
```

My third attempt was to use System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter, but this returns the error message: "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed."

Example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 2.3)";
byte[] bytes = (byte[])ExecuteSelect(cmd).Rows[0][0];
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
decimal d = (decimal)bf.Deserialize(ms);
```

My current solution is to pass the type of the value into the stored procedure and us a case statement to convert the value into a string.

My preferred solution would be if I could access MS SQL's Convert function from .Net without connecting to a database.

I do not want to use a homegrown function to do the conversions.  I need a solution that is reliable.

My environment is .Net 2008, C# or VB

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it an option to have an additional column to specify the type?  Otherwise, do you control the data that goes into the table and the code the reads it out?

Comment: Woah there! Why are you converting anything? Put it in as a blob (parameter with a byte[] value); get it back as a blob (GetValue() returns byte[]). no strings attached...

Comment: Also; in my opinion (based on extensive work with serialisation) you should NOT use BinaryFormatter here; it is platform specific, version-intolerant (making it brittle and hard to guarantee you can read your data later), and has a habit of edge-cases such as events causing failure. Seriously; I DO NOT think that is a good idea. Binary serialization is fine, just not with BinaryFormatter

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt was close, there is [`BitConverter.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble.aspx) or whatever you want to convert it to.

Your second attempt was also close, you just didn't rewind the stream before reading it (and what a crazy roundabout way that was...).

As to your 3rd attempt, you still haven't learned your lesson regarding I/O.

Edit: I am not convinced that you're getting a decimal out of that thing. You should double check your types...

Comment: I tried using BitConverter, but it does not seem to work.  In the database I will convert 2.3 to binary and then BitConvert.ToDouble will return 4.88141923657287E-313.  This is similar for integers as well. I tried setting the Position = 0 for both stream methods, but I get the same error messages.

Comment: Try giving an actual type to `2.3` in your `select`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I can do SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,3), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 2.3)) and this will return 2.3 as a decimal, but then I am doing the conversion in the DB.  I would prefer to return the binary data and convert it to a decimal in .Net, but it seems that .Net and MSSQL encode binary data differently.